# How to fix user access to authorized pages by click on backward button in browsers

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to build login page by paasportjs library, this is my code, it work without error but whenever one user login successfully and when it logout successfully  other user without  permission(without login) can see this user's pages, only by click on backward button in browser, I am going to know how I can fix backward problem issue?

```
//Login Section

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: "email",
            passwordField: "password",
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        (email, password, done) => {
            User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'The email is not registered' })
                    }

                    //Match password
                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
                        if (err) throw err;

                        if (result) {
                            return done(null, user)
                        } else {
                            return done(null, false, { message: "Password incorrect" })
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })

)
```

//Serrializer and deserializer section

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
})
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        console.log('deserializing user:', user);
        done(err, user);
    });
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8008, process.env.ip, function() {
    console.log('Server is running!');
});
```

Comment: next time if you ask a question, please try to locate the problem instead of showing us 4 big code snippets and let us find where that problem could be.

Comment: actually, my problem is login problem, Login not work or when I could login to authenticate page, other users are not authenticate can see page without login!.It's really complicated for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the apis which return the pages which you want only authenticated users to see add

> passport.isAuthenticated

for user to be logged in and  to check the authorization of the user

> passport.isAuthorized

during defining the route of that api.You can use both in the same request as well. for Example in your code for /dashboard api

```
app.get('/dashboard', passport.isAuthenticated, passport.isAuthorized('user'), (req, res) => {

    res.render('dashboard', {
        pageName: 'Navid'

    })
})



passport.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {  
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.status(401);
    return next({"ERR MSG"});
};

passport.isAuthorized = (userType) => {
       return (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.user.userType == userType) {        
            return next();
        }        
        res.status(403);
        return next({"ERR MSG HERE"});
    };
};
```

these are the passport middleware you need to add in your code

Comment: TypeError: passport.isAuthorized is not a function

Comment: I edited the original answer with the authentication functions. user type us like user or admin etc

Comment: thank you but I got "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}' " and ReferenceError: isAuthenticated is not defined

Comment: put these below serielization and deserializeUser functions. you should remove syntax error by yourself. and once the syntax is resolved, the other issue should be resolved

Comment: it seems passed and goes to dashbord but instead of show dashboard showed [object Object]

Comment: my code had many problems such as: extra unnecessary "id" in my monogoose schema, wrong bcrypt.compare() and wrong serializer...  but your code solved my main problem, thank you, moreover I think It would be better if your code run after paasport.use(new LocalStrategy({...